# text processing: if condition and loop inside another loop

Tags: python, text

I have a text file. Once a pattern match happens I want to print the lines until the next pattern is found.

```
for line in text:
    if pattern in line:
        if another_pattern in line:
             print all the lines until pattern_X is found.
             Continue with the execution from the next line
```

This should be done for the entire text, i.e the patterns 'pattern' and 'another_pattern' will match more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable to keep track of whether you're in a section you should print.

In pseudo code, it could look like:

```
needToPrint = False
for line in text:
  if needToPrint:
    print line
  if pattern in line:
    needToPrint = True
  if another_pattern in line:
    needToPrint = False
```

(but pay attention in particular to limit conditions if you're going to use this snippet)

Comment: so it should work, because as long as we don't see the ending pattern, then `needToPrint` will be true, and hence we'll print the line